# I need help using manipulate solve and plot in the same time

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

So this is my code so far

```
h[x_]:=x^2
Manipulate[NSolve[h'[l] == (h[b] - h[a])/(b - a), l]; 
 Plot[{h[x], h'[l] (x - l) + h[l]}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, -5, 0}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

I want it to show the second part of the plot while I change `a` and `b` but it only shows `h[x]`. Can somebody help? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
h[x_] := x^2
Manipulate[sol = NSolve[h'[l] == (h[b] - h[a])/(b - a), l];
 Plot[Evaluate[{h[x], h'[l] (x - l) + h[l]} /. sol], {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-50, 100}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sinka, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.